# Comparison of perimeter of hyperbolic polygons

Tags: computational-geometry

Let `$P_{4k}(\alpha)$` be the regular, hyperbolic, `$4k$-sided` polygon with each interior angle `$\alpha$` Where `$\alpha\geq \frac{\pi}{2}$`. Suppose `$Q_{4m}$` and `$Q_{4n}$` are any two regular hyperbolic polygons such that

```
$$area(P_{4k}(\alpha)) = area(Q_{4m})+area(Q_{4n})$$.
```

Does the following inequality holds true?

```
$$perim(P_{4k}(\alpha)) = perim(Q_{4m}) + perim(Q_{4n}).$$
```

Comment: $perim(P)$ denotes the perimeter of the polygon $P$

Comment: Hyperbolic polygons ???

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the question right. All four polygons have a multiple of 4 vertices. The area of the lower two polygons is equal to the area of the top polygon but the sum of the perimeter of the lower two polygons is clearly greater than the perimeter of the top polygon.

[image]